# What is the fastest way to put bloom on a BufferedImage?

Tags: java, game-development, bufferedimage, bloom

So I make games in Java, and a big part of that is rendering. Recently, I've been getting into post-processing and I wanted to add bloom to my frame. I found a library that adds bloom to an image, but as it turns out, it's very slow. Before bloom, it's around 40-50 fps (I don't have the best pc, and haven't figured out multithreading yet), but after bloom, it drops to 15 fps. Is there a library that adds bloom to an image faster? Is there a faster way in general? Should I just bite the bullet and learn multithreading? For context, I'm drawing my frame on a BufferedImage and then drawing that to a JPanel.

No Bloom:
[No Bloom: 40 fps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEd3e.png)

Bloom:
[Bloom: 12 fps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PIgt.png)

Comment: I have little to no experience with game development, especially in Java, but I would think such things should be done by the GPU, not the CPU. However, I have no advice on how to accomplish that in your program.